# How to proxy both WSGI and ASGI via Uvicorn or Daphne with nginx and SSL proxy?

Tags: docker, nginx, wsgi, lets-encrypt, asgi

I have a small project that uses Django Channels (websockets) and it works fine locally. I've added SSL to my docker-based deployment with the `letsencrypt-companion-container` docker image, which, exposes 443, handles all the SSL, then funnels requests/responses vi port 80 into my A/WSGI adapter (uvicorn or daphne).

When under SSL, my client code is getting this error in the JS console:

```
`WebSocket connection to 'wss://my_server.com/ws/echo/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404`
```

It isn't clear to me why. How do I make this work?

Here is my nginx.conf, if it helps:

```
upstream wsgi {
    server web:8000;
}

upstream asgi {
    server web:8000;
}

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://wsgi;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /ws {
        proxy_pass ​http://asgi;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    }

    location /staticfiles/ {
        alias /home/app/web/staticfiles/;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm facing now the same issue, so have you solved it? if so I would appreciate  if you can send me the details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing a similar issue, I got a 403 error on my django server. After checking [this](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/589)  and setting my `ALLOWED_HOSTS = "*"` the server worked.

Being honest it doesn't look like a best practice to me, but while I find something better, is a way to have the server up and running.

Make sure also that you include [this configuration](https://www.uvicorn.org/deployment/#running-behind-nginx) on your nginx